# Magento2: How to connect Magento website to an external webservice?

Tags: magento2, web-services

I have a Magento website that I want to connect to an external webservice to upload and update the website with products from my DB directly, can this be done? if so, please advise how.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to modify the file env.php?

is located in public_html/app/etc/

give it a look